# Run PsExec from C# with admin right without UAC

Tags: c#, uac, psexec

I want to run a `PSExec` action, that need admin right, from a `C#` app launch from user space. Of course, the complication, that's I don't want the UAC.

I want to run an action like this:

```
PsExec.exe -i -s powershell.exe -command "whoami *> 'out.txt'"
```

- If I run example in cmd/powershell with admin right, it's work.
- If I run example in C# exe with process with `verb = "runas"`, it's working
- If I run example in C# exe with process with user/password/domain, it's not working

I've tried a lot of other things, but I've not find a good trick. (powershell with credential, run a .bat or .ps1, ...)

I'm open to every solution and/or if it's really doable.

Comment: Why use `psexec` at all? What are you trying to do? You can create and execute a Powershell pipeline in code, you don't need `psexec` or `Process.Start`. On the other hand, you *can't* just bypass the UAC warning. If it was that easy, it would be useless as a security measure

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Windows is a secure operating system, and you need to be an administrator to perform administrator tasks.

Pretend for a moment that UAC doesn't exist.

- pretend that we're back on Windows XP
- you are a standard user
- and you want to use `PsExec` to run something as the **`System`** account

You cannot. A standard user is not allowed to compromise the security of the system like that.

The only way you *can* do that is to run as an Administrator.

- On Windows XP, you would have to logoff, and get an administrator to login for you

Windows Vista, and UAC, made it easier than having to completely switch to another user:

- you can just enter their credentials in the UAC dialog (or press Continue)

But you cannot just arbitrarily elevate yourself to an administrator - that defeats the entire purpose of having a secure operating system.